# Alternatives to Scrollbars and Pagination

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, scrollbar, concept

Our app shows data in tables with millions of rows. Normally we use here pagination as navigation through the tables. Last year we tested a scrollbar which dynamically loads the content of the table (it only loads the rows which are shown on the screen). But the second method isn't very good for touch devices. Are there any alternatives to pagination and scrollbars? We also use filters, but I´m not very happy with them.

Comment: If you can categorize these rows, you can make the user initially scroll trough a list of categories, and then click to expand it. From there, you may use preferrably a infinite scrollbar, with a scrollbar that allows the user to go to a specific point of the list (Like Android's contacts screen)

Comment: "second method isn´t very good for touch devices" why not? performance? than you could preload the next n items.

Comment: Okay, this could be a way. Every 15 minutes we get a new line with new measured data. So we could categorize it in years, months, ... The scrollbar could be a bit tricky, but possible. Thank you for your suggestion. @Kroltan

Comment: @nilsK no, performance isn´t the problem, we preload allways about 500 rows. I think scrollbars are not typical on touch devices. The scrollbuttons would be too small (and bigger ones would take away to much room). Furthermore my colleagues don´t want to have custom scrollbars in the app.

Comment: @nilsK It's not intuitive. The most similar thing to pagination you'll see is Google's (Play Store, etc) tabs, and that isn't very pleasant either.